# Problem with indoor palm in UK

Tags: indoors, palm

Hello fellow palm owners

I have a Phoenix Robelini that I’ve had for about 6 years, grown indoors( summer spells outside) and has always been in the same spot and been a happy palm.

There have been some new and less than wonderful developments:

Last year it started to develop brown/yellow leaf spots on the lower leaves. This happened whilst a friend was staying during a three week holiday. I sprayed it will Rose Clear, put it outside and all seemed to recover reasonably well. Spots obviously remained
This year the leaves are generally lighter in colour, slight pinking in some leaves, with mild spotting returning on newer growth.
The new growth is taking months to slowly unfurl and the old leaves are uncharacteristically looking somewhat lacklustre
As it was seriously pot bound I repotted it( Perlite, Innes no2,Lakeland Gold) left it in the same position outside and then brought it in for the winter.

It’s not the same happy palm it’s been and I’m wondering what I’ve done and what I can do to bring it back to vibrant life.

I’ve attached photo’s that hopefully give a back ground to the situation.

Any suggestions/questions would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Symon
[image: palm1]
[image: palm2]

Comment: Can you look closely on the underside of the leaves and take a picture?  Bugs often hide out of sight there...